# Spring ApplicationContext not cached for integration testing with Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, integration-testing

When integration tests start from IDE ApllicationContext loads only once and then shared between tests and it works as aspected. But executing `mvn clean install` new ApllicationContext created per every test. According [Spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching) I've configured 
*maven-failsafe-plugin* to use single fork

```
<artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.12.4</version>
 <configuration>
    <forkCount>1</forkCount>
    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
...
```

To cache ApplicationContext used followin annotation:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
```

Why context not shared when building application with maven? 
Actually is there is any other way speed up IT tests? Thanks.

**UPDATED:**

This is multimodule Maven project. Accordig [Spring IT caching doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching)

> To benefit from the caching mechanism, all tests must run within the
>   same process or test suite. This can be achieved by executing all
>   tests as a group within an IDE. Similarly, when executing tests with a
>   build framework such as Ant, Maven, or Gradle it is important to make
>   sure that the build framework does not fork between tests. For
>   example, if the forkMode for the Maven Surefire plug-in is set to
>   always or pertest, the TestContext framework will not be able to cache
>   application contexts between test classes and the build process will
>   run significantly slower as a result.

So for [maven-failsafe-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html) 2.14 this config equals *forkMode=once*

Comment: Could you add more details about your test configs and overall structure

Comment: @AliDehghani currently I run tests in single module. when do it in local env can check with visualvm that with <forkMode>never</forkMode> shared context but it also creates 2000+ threads (while forkMode=once about 20) thats why many tests failures

Comment: did you tried to set `threadCount=1`?

Comment: @AliDehghani http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html The attribute thread-count allows you to specify how many threads should be allocated for this execution. Only makes sense to use in conjunction with the parallel parameter. so that means cannot be used for forking or I've missed smth?

Comment: Did you found a solution on this? forkcount 1 and reuseForks true does not work for me as well. From the IDE - Spring Boot context in initialized only once, but with maven it is restarting it everytime.Thanks a lot in advance! @njjnex

Answer (score 3):

Few things you may want to look into:

- version of the surefire plugin and the parallel execution configuration. According to the [Surefire Fork Options](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html) - the *forkCount* and *reuseForks* are parameters for Surefire version 2.14 or later. The pom file snippet in OP states version 2.12.4
- there seems to be something in your configuration that still causes parallel execution. In the case where 20 threads are launched, I expect that 20 application contexts are created and cached, so that all the tests executed by one thread are (re)-using the application context created for it. If that is the case, the behavior is expected in the context of multiple threads running tests - the question becomes adjusting the configuration to the number of threads desired
- may want to experiment with various versions of Surefire, the behavior of parallel execution may differ. I've used Surefire 2.16 in other projects and without any custom configuration related to forking, all tests are executed single threaded (as the default configuration states it should)

I know this is rather a list of more things to try than a definitive answer to the OP, but I posted in the hope it might be helpful

Comment: thank you for your answer, plugin version is ok, actually it's true that threads count equals to number AppContexts cached, and one question still remains - why when AppContext  cached  and forkMode=never visualvm shows that there created 2000+ threads why it happens and how to manage theads count in that case?

Comment: That is a very good question - to narrow it down, I suggest to create a sample project, keep the POM file configuration identical with your project (to the extent possible) and add few dummy tests that use the spring AppContext. Set the forkMode to never and if you see the 2000+ threads in the VM then you know is the maven+surefire giving you this behavior. If you see only one thread, that tells you the threading comes from somewhere else (test frameworks involved, tests harness, test themselves, etc).

Answer (score 2):

You can try with specifiyng context location instead of classes:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:test-context.xml")
```

Spring caches application contexts by `locations` attribute so if the same `locations` appears for the second time, Spring uses the same context rather than creating a new one.

It's from here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testing-ctx-management

Also you can read about speeding up unit tests here:
http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2010/12/speeding-up-spring-integration-tests.html

**UPDATE**

Is your project a multi module Maven project?
Accordingly to the docs:

> The default setting is forkCount=1/reuseForks=true, which means that Surefire creates one new JVM process to execute all tests in one maven module.

Comment: classes are also used for context caching in Spring 4.x http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching

Comment: tests in single module also not sharing context